# How to add reactions to messages in discord.py without id

Tags: discord, discord.py, addition, message

I am new to discord.py coding. I can't find the I'd for arrow up emoji... I've tried `client.emojis` and others but it doesnt work... pls help or send me all the ids or a website to see all the ids

Answer (score 2):

just type your emoji in `:this:` form and stic an `\` before the emojiname thats it!

when you send it it will come as `<:something:1234567890123>`

copy the numbers at the end thats your emoji `id`

same can be done with members and channels just instead of `:this:` do `:@random_dude:` and for channels do `#general`

hope this helps! Goodluck on your development!

Comment: on the desktop client it works perfectly fine. this is for custom emojis only. regular emojis just become regular unicode based emojis based on your OS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code looks like, but if you're interacting with your 'message' asyncs you could do this.

```
emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
# or '\U0001f44d' or ''
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

If you can, can you add your code so I can see where your error might be?

Answer (score 1):

As zjbrown said, the thumbs up emoji can be stored in a string (and sent) using `"\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}"`, `"\U0001f44d"`, or `""`.

You can google a built-in emoji's name to find websites that have emoji descriptions. Sometimes these sites also have the unicode name, but this is not guranteed. If you want to send a custom emoji, you will have to find the emoji's id.

For built-in emojis, you can use [RoboDanny's `charinfo` command](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/rewrite/cogs/meta.py#L292) (you'll have to add it to your own bot or use the RoboDanny bot in the discord.py support server) to get the unicode name.

If it is a custom emoji, you can send it in chat and get the image url (right click -> copy url). Then, look for the string of numbers before the `.png` and copy that. (Numbers only - don't copy the beginning of the url!) You can then send custom emojis by using the string `<:[emoji name]:[emoji id]>` for static emojis and `<a:[emoji name]:[emoji id]>` for animated emojis.